# Numerical presentation of a term

Tags: numerical-methods, computer-arithmetic

Hello I have the following task:

Let 
$$ y = \sin(x + \delta) -\ sin (x)$$
and $$\delta > 0$$ is very small. Write down a mathematical equivalent representation of this term which is stable.

I'm not sure if the word "stable" is the right translation (in german it's "gutartig"), I have this definition of it: An operation $$\circ$$ is stable if $$z*=z(1+\epsilon_{x \circ y})$$ with $$|\epsilon_{x \circ y}| \le C_1|\epsilon_x|+C_2|\epsilon_y|$$ with moderate constants $$C_1,C_2$$ which are independant from $$\epsilon_x,\epsilon_y$$

Still I have absolutely no clue how I do solve this task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that if $\delta$ is small, the difference in the sines can be much smaller than either of the sines.  You will lose precision, which you should have seen problems about before (maybe without the sine function involved).  You should have seen things like $0.5000001-0.50000000$  The cure for this is to do the subtraction analytically.  If you expand $\sin(x+\delta)$ what do you get?  Now distribute out the factor $\sin x$ and use the  small angle approximation for the terms involving $\delta$.

Comment: Hello, I'm not really familiar with the small angle approximation. So I got $$y=sin(x)(cos(\delta)-1)+sin(\delta)cos(x)$$ Do I now only substitute the terms with $$\delta$$ meaning this: $$y=sin(x)(1-1)+\delta cos(x)=\delta cos(x)$$? Or do I also concern about the terms with $$x$$? And what is exactly the substitute for the cosinus? The german wikipedia says it's 1 in the english version it's $$1-(\delta)/2$$ Thank you.

Comment: That would be the first order.  For $\delta \ll 1, \cos \delta \approx 1-\frac 12\delta^2$.  The first order is a good way to calculate it and the second order gives a good feel for the error.  These are the first terms in the Taylor series for $\sin$ and $\cos$

Answer (score 0):

Note also that 
$$\sin A -\sin B=2\sin\frac{A-B}2\,\cos\frac{A+B}2$$
so that
$$ 
\sin(x+δ)-\sin(x)=2\sin\left(\frac δ2\right)\,\cos\left(x+\frac δ2\right)
$$ 
is a stable method to evaluate this difference for small $δ$ without resorting to approximations.